# Performing prediction on pdf in GCP Bucket using Node js: invalid argument

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-automl-nl

On Google Cloud Platform (GCP) I have an AutoML Natural Language entity extraction model trained on PDFs. It thus needs to perform predictions on PDFs.

I have a PDF I want to perform an entity extraction prediction inside a GCP Bucket, thus I want to make the following request in NodeJS and call `predict` using `PredictionServiceClient`:

This code sample was based on the entity extraction example on normal text from [Entity Extraction NodeJS Text example](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/predict#automl_language_entity_extraction_predict-nodejs), and the NodeJS AutoML NL docs to find what the `IPredictRequest` looks like: [AutoML Google API docs IPredictRequest](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/automl/latest/google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.PredictRequest.html).

```
const projectId = 'projectId';
const location = 'us-central1';
const datasetId = 'TEN4565454654564855555'; // randomised for this example
const srcFilename = 'file_name.pdf';

// Imports the Google Cloud AutoML library
const {PredictionServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/automl').v1;

// Instantiates a client
const client = new PredictionServiceClient();

const request = {
    name: client.modelPath(projectId, location, datasetId),
    payload: {
      document: {
        inputConfig: {
          gcsSource: {
            inputUris: ["gs://bucket_name/" + srcFilename]
          }
        }
      }
    },
  };

const [response] = await client.predict(request);
```

Then I get error:

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument. at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:179:52) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181) at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument. at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:179:52) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181) at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

I have also tried it with using underscores in `input_config` instead of `inputConfig` and the same for `gcs_source` and `input_uris`. I tried this because this is what an example `request.json`  looks like on the NL model Test&Use page (see image).

[![Example request.json][3]][3]
Then I get:

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: List of found errors: 1.Field: payload.document.document_text.content; Message: Required field not set. at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:179:52) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181) at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: List of found errors: 1.Field: payload.document.document_text.content; Message: Required field not set. at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:179:52) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141) at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181) at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

In the NodeJS NL docs it says that `documentText` is optional, so I don't understand this error. Trying to fix this last error by supplying the `document_text` field created the first error in this post again (and I don't want to have to supply the text in the PDF manually, since it is a photocopy).

**How do I fix this and more importantly how do I parse/understand the documentation and error messages? Why camelcase in some places and using underscores in others?**

Comment: I tested your code using my own model, and just added an `async` function to get the response. I was able to get results from it so I can confirm that your code is working. I tried replacing all the values with incorrect ones, and I can only get the `Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: List of found errors: 1.Field: ` when I used an incorrect `datasetId`. Can you double check if you are using the correct `datasetId`?

Comment: Also please mask your `projectId` and `datasetId` on your screenshot.